# What is the process about cgi writes value to environment variable of cgi script process

Tags: python, cgi

I do a simple cgi test with the command `"python -m CGIHTTPServer 9000"` 
to handle GET request and cgi script code like:

```
data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
```

and it works, data will be set to string like `"m=4&n=4"`.

So how is the value from? Yeah, it is from cgi environment variable "QUERY_STRING", and
then I use command `"ps -p -wwwE"` to check all the environment variables of CGIHTTPServer process, there is no name called "QUERY_STRING".

How can I find the cgi environment variables, and what is the process?

**Answer**:
[CGIHTTPServer.py](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.6/file/ba31940588b6/Lib/CGIHTTPServer.py)

Answer (score 2):

The CGI environment variables are set up by your web server for the life of the request when it executes the CGI.

[See the CGI spec for the full list of environment variables.](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) Some web servers have local extensions to this specification as well.

Also see [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) for some Python-specific examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried these code and it worked well, maybe this question would be how the web server to set CGI environment variables and where these env vars stored?

Comment: If I am understanding your question, the answer is specific to the web server you are using. In the case of Python's CGIHTTPServer, the environment variables are set up in the `run_cgi` function, just before the server forks to run your CGI. You can [look at the source code](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.6/file/ba31940588b6/Lib/CGIHTTPServer.py) to see Python's CGIHTTPServer implementation.

Comment: Oh, that is it. Sorry for my poor English. Thank you for your link, I will read the source code file.